# jQuery prepending textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<textarea id="photo-42-9" class="comment_box">Write a comment...</textarea>
```

jQuery code that doesn't work, what am I missing?

```
$('#photo-42-9').prepend("<div>blah</div>");
```

**EDIT**
Corrected the ids mismatch, still doesn't work though

Comment: Could be a typo ? The id you are selecting is photo-42-99 and the id on the element is photo-42-9.

Comment: `<textarea id="photo-42-9">...</textarea>` has a different ID from the one you are using here `$('#photo-42-99').prepend("<div>blah</div>");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prepend()` adds the specified mark-up into the object returned by the jQuery selector (in this case the `textarea`). A `textarea` can contain only text, no other child elements; therefore you're trying to create invalid html.

If you want to put the `<div>` *before* the `textarea`:

```
$('<div>blah</div>').insertBefore('#photo-42-9');
```

If you want to prepend new text into the `textarea`:

```
$('#photo-42-9').val(
    function(i,val){
        return 'blah ' + val;
    });
```

References:

- [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: I'll try, but what is it that you want to do..?

Comment: Yes, on second thoughts, I think this is probably what the OP is trying to do... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWWqa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a `textarea` element are treated as text, not as HTML. They are parsed into the element's `value` property.  You can't edit the *content* of the element: you have to edit its value.

The nice, jQuery-ish way of doing this is with [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) and its callback syntax:

```
$('#photo-42-9').val(function(i, oldVal) {
    return "<div>blah</div>" + oldVal; // return the desired value
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWWqa/)

Note that I have also corrected the selector: you had an additional `9` in the ID, so it wouldn't have found the element.

Comment: This is a bit nicer than my suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

@Bob: In addition to what David Thomas said, your item has an id of `photo-42-9` and your selector is looking for `photo-42-99`

Suggested Fix:

```
$('#photo-42-99').text( $('#photo-42-99').text() + "<div>blah</div>" );
```